# Programmatically capture the current screen shot in LG WebOS TV

Tags: websocket, webos, java-websocket, lg, smart-tv

I am trying to the screenshot of the LG TV. Running nmap gives me the following output.

```
Discovered open port 18181/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Increased max_successful_tryno for xx.xx.xx.xxx to 1 (packet drop)
Discovered open port 9998/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 9955/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 1998/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 3001/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 1267/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 1512/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 3000/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 1812/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 1552/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
Discovered open port 36866/tcp on xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

Now, How i can get the screen shot of the current program running in the TV.

Thank you

---

Wondering How, i can get the screenshot of the TV ?

---

This code is used to turnOff the TV sending message via WebSocket

```
public static void turnOff(WebSocketClient ws) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject headers = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();

    try {
        headers.put("type", "request");
        headers.put("id", 10001);
        headers.put("uri",  "ssap://system/turnOff");

    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }

    headers.put("payload", payload);
    ws.send(headers.toString());

    System.out.println(headers.toString());
}
```

---

This is the code that connects to the WebSocket in the TV

```
      ws = new WebSocketClient(URI.create("ws://10.10.10.111:3000")) {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake arg0) {
             System.out.println("Connected ws://10.10.10.111:9000");
  try {
      // sendPin(ws);
       register(ws);
  } catch (JSONException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(LGWebTVClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }                 
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String arg0) {
            try {
                System.out.println(arg0);
                JSONObject  message = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    message = new JSONObject(arg0);
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(LGWebTVClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                String type = message.optString("type");                    


                try
                {
                    String pin ="";
                    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                    {

                       if(type.equals("response"))
                       {
                        String id = message.optString("id");    
                        if(id.equals("152463"))
                        {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                System.out.println("Enter the PIN: ");
                int number = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Integer input: " + number);                               



                pin = number+"";

                                if(number < 10)
                                    pin ="00"+pin;

                                if(number < 99 && number > 9)
                                    pin ="0"+pin;

                                if(i > 99)
                                    pin =""+pin;
                System.out.println("Sending PIN");
                sendPin(ws,pin);
                break;                                    
                        }
                       }
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException ex) 
                {

                }


                if(type.equals("registered"))
                {
                      System.out.println("Registerd");
                      secondScreen(ws);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

[You could convert the HTML content into a canvas](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/08/take-webpage-screenshot-html5-jquery-javascript.html), then save it as a file.

However, this only renders HTML and CSS directly.  It cannot capture anything outside of that.

Or, it might be possible to use `getUserMedia()` to [take a screenshot of everything, and save that as a file](https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/6403122).